# Calculating total average percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css

trying to calculate the average of from Response Percent of each months from  Jan to Dec  display the average in the total average. I tried all the possible ways by looking at examples and posts from online but nothing seems to be working.

In new to javascript and learning throught online class and looking posts online but its not helping. can any one help me figure it out

```js
const $select_rows = $('.select_row');
const $percent_row = $('.percent_row');

function update_column(col_index) {
  const child_index = col_index + 2; // 1 indexed plus 1 for row heading
  const $selects = $select_rows.find('td:nth-child(' + child_index + ') select');

  if ($selects.length) {
    let yes_count = 0;
    $selects.each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        yes_count++;
      }
    });

    $percent_row.find('td:nth-child(' + child_index + ') .cnt-percent-y').text((yes_count * 100 / $selects.length).toFixed(2));
  }
}

function setup() {
  $select_rows.each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').each(function(index) {
      const col_index = index;

      $(this).change(function() {
        update_column(col_index);
      });

      update_column(col_index);
    });
  });
}

setup();

function average(perResponse) {

  var total = 0;
  var perResponse;
  for (var i = 0; i < perResponse.length; i++) {
    total += perResponse[i];
  }
  var avg = total / source.length;
  alert(avg)
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = avg;
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<title>Finding Average</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p style="font-family:georgia,garamond,serif;font-size:16px;font-style:italic;">
    Finding Average & Calculation of Total Percentage
  </p>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sept</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Total Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Bought Office Supplies</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Saving's Over $25,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Savings</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $10,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $20,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="percent_row">
        <td>Response Percent</td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td> //Here goes the average total from calculation from the average from Jan to Dec
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Comment: "_is not working_" is not a problem description. Please explain what you want the code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: I didn't find anywhere you use the average function!

Comment: average function is never called. first call that, and then try to verify if you are passing right value of perResponse.

Comment: sorry im new to javascript and im learning though online class and my notes. can you help me correct it –

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your  "average()" function:
"source.length" in your is not initialized - or maybe you intended to use "perResponse.length" instead?

Aside from that "var perRseponse;" seems to be an unnecessary declaration of your parameter (plus typo).

Comment: sorry im new to javascript and im learning though online class and my notes. can you help me correct it